# Visual Studio complains about using C# 8 language features when the LanguageVersion is set to 9 with ReSharper 2019 installed

Tags: visual-studio-2019, resharper, .net-5

I have a very odd problem where I will apply a recommended change that uses a C# 8.0 language feature (in this example I'll use compound assignment). I then get a red squiggly with the following message...

> C# 8.0 language feature

This is a net5.0 project I have tried setting my language version property to any of the following...

`<LangVersion>9</LangVersion>`

`<LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>`

`<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`

All of them show the same behaviour. The only way I can get the error to go away is by setting the property to `8` or `8.0` which seems a somewhat retrograde step!

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I'm fully patched and up to date as of the time of writing, along with the latest version of ReSharper.

The code will compile without problems but the squiggles are generating noise. Has anyone else found this and has any ideas how to make it go away?

Comment: I have looked at the ReSharper site too and there is an option to set the language version 
on the right click menu for each project - It's probably linked to this as I can't seem to select 9.0 on there it's set to 'default'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it was a ReSharper issue - JetBrains have introduced a new tool called Jetbrains Toolbox that seems to manage their updates now. My installed package was telling me it was up to date when it wasn't - I looked deeper and I was running ReSharper 2019.1 and not 2021.1